# Profile Views with alternative levels of disclosure

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails 4 app which contains a model called Projects.

The Projects model has publication options which allow project creators to make the project public, private, or to make a teaser version of the project public.

If the third option is selected, then some but not all of the project details will be visible to some users, whilst the full project will be visible to other users.

How do I approach this? If I create a second layout for the partially disclosed version, can I then yield some of the model attributes and not others? Is there a better way to go about this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go about using view based conditions. It gives you one file to edit and adjust for the future and will only render the information that you want the users to be able to access.

```
- if project.private or project.teaser
  #this is my private or teaser information
- if project.private
  #this is my private information

#this is my public information
```